# npm: could not resolve dependency tree (conflict)

Tags: npm, dependencies, version, npm-install, resolve

I'm building React UI library and I bumped into a problem resolving dependencies between my packages. My current package depends on my other packages and now I'm trying to install all dependencies into my working **@kelysty/npm-template**:

**I RUN**: `npm i`

**ERROR** (working bash terminal)

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @kelysty/npm-template@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: eslint@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^8.54.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^8.0.0" from @kelysty/eslint-config@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@kelysty/eslint-config
npm ERR!   dev @kelysty/eslint-config@"^1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

**Dependencies of package.json file of WORKING pkg** (partial)

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@kelysty/eslint-config": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
  },
```

**Dependencies of package.json file of pkg that I INSTALL** (partial)

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

Just install packages. I cannot see how this error occurs: `peerDeps` of eslint-config requires eslint of **^8.0.0** to be installed, while `devDeps` of my working dir are installing **^8.54.0**. How this is an error?! Hod does pkg resolving works then?!

**I'VE TRIED**

None of these helped:

- --legacy-peer-deps
- --force
- npm update
- npm ci
- removing package-lock.json and node_modules
- reading about deps resolving (didn't find good article, so here we are)

**PS**

I can provide whole lists of dependencies of both projects if you think it's gonna help.
Just didn't want to litter ticket

Comment: Did you tried installing the eslint version 8.0.0 in your dev dependencies? Like `npm i eslint@8.0.0 --save-dev`

Comment: I've just cleaned cache with `npm cache clean --force` and then tried adding `npm i -D eslint@8.0.0` and `npm i -D eslint@8.54.0`. In both cases outputs remain the same error... But thank you anyway)

Comment: It's seems like I 'm missing something about dependencies... Because, if I remove `devDep` **eslint** from the working directory, then the same thing happens again but for prettier: `devDep` **3.0.1** in the root cannot satisfy **3.0.0** in the `peerDep` of the uploading pkg